# Placing UIViews one after another

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, view

I have a view controller which has an array of subviews. These subviews are custom UIViews to be placed one after another vertically. The subviews are not consistent in height; their height is based on the data used when instantiating them. Additionally, I want to support device rotations so that the subview's UILabels will expand horizontally in landscape mode and be shorter.

I'm having lots of trouble accomplishing this in a good way. When the view controller is laying out it's subviews, I feel like I have no clean way of figuring out how tall each subview is (because I have instantiated them at this point, but not set their frames). Please refer to my code below to understand my frustration.

I would really like it if the **`layoutSubviews`** method of the subviews were called before the **`viewWillLayoutSubviews`** method of the view controller, but that is not the case.

**`MyViewController.m`**

```
....

- (void)initWithDataObjects:(NSArray*)dataObjects
{
    _dataObjects = dataObjects;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mySubviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (DataObject* do in _dataObjects) {
        MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithDataObject:do];
        [mySubviews addObject:customView];
        [self.view addSubview:customView];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    int currentHeight = 0;
    for (MyCustomView *customView in mySubviews) {

        int subviewHeight = customView.frame.size.height;
        // PROBLEM: subviewHeight is 0 because the subview hasn't called layoutSubviews yet..

        [customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, subviewHeight)];
        currentHeight += subviewHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the proble they arent aligned properly in the view??

Comment: the way coded above, all the subviews would be on top of each other

Comment: i made a hacky way of doing it where i had a calculateHeight method in the subview which would do some logic to figure out how tall the subview would be...i feel it is definitely not the right way though - since that work is already getting done in the layoutSubviews method of the subview

Comment: 1. There is no `[self.view addSubview:...]`. Do you add those views as subviews? 2. You can layout them in `layoutSubview` method. 3. If you want to calculate subviews size inside, you can override `sizeThatFits:` and return proper size that way. Then, won't have troubles in layout subviews.

Comment: first change current height to cgfloat or float type,and all int variables that you use

Comment: @MaciejOczko sorry edited post, i did have addsubview in my code. I do lay them out in the **`layoutSubviews`** method but that gets called after the view controller's **`viewWillLayoutSubviews`** method. Overriding sizeThatFits seems like a hacky solution. In my custom view, I already calculate the size that fits by setting all it's subview's frames...so this seems like double work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm editing and summarizing based on the comments that came below:

Here is the order these methods get called:

```
2013-10-24 01:05:11.391 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[MyViewController viewDidLoad]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.395 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[MyViewController addMySubViews]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.395 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view1 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.395 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view2 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.395 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view3 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.398 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[MyViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.398 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[MyViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.398 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view1 layoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.398 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view2 layoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:05:11.398 MyTestApp[34166:70b] -[view3 layoutSubviews]
```

Your best bet is to take your sizing code out of your view's layoutSubviews, and put it in a separate view method (maybe mySize) and call that method from the viewcontroller in viewWillLayoutSubviews, and you can also call it from the view's layoutSubviews (so you don't have duplicate code).

This may be what it would look like (viewWillLayoutSubviews is calling all the subviews' mySize methods):

```
2013-10-24 01:38:10.501 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[MyViewController viewDidLoad]
2013-10-24 01:38:10.501 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[MyViewController addMySubViews]
2013-10-24 01:38:10.501 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view1 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:38:10.501 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view2 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:38:10.502 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view3 didMoveToSuperview]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.396 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[MyViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.396 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view1 mySize]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.396 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view2 mySize]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.396 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view3 mySize]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.397 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[MyViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.397 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view1 layoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.397 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view2 layoutSubviews]
2013-10-24 01:38:24.397 MyTestApp[34850:70b] -[view3 layoutSubviews]
```

BTW, if you change the frame of your subviews from within the viewcontroller, it will trigger a needsLayout on the subview, and an eventual layoutSubviews.

Comment: I do add subviews in viewDidLoad and I do set the frames in layoutSubviews, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: viewDidLoad is being called before the other methods. However, the view controller's array of subviews...their layoutSubviews method is not called until after the view controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews. However, in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method, I need to know the subviews' height - which I get from laying them out in layoutSubviews...

Comment: I guess I keep misunderstanding you.  Why do you think that viewWillLayoutSubviews should get called BEFORE layoutSubviews?  As far as I know, viewWillLayoutSubviews is giving you advance warning that layoutSubviews is going to be called.
Is there some reason why you need values in viewWillLayoutSubviews?  Can you skip viewWillLayoutSubviews and just do everything in layoutSubviews?

Comment: yeah we're on completely different wavelengths...I don't think that viewWillLayoutSubviews should get called before layoutSubviews...I'm talking about the viewWillLayoutSubviews method of the view controller and the layoutSubviews method of the subviews. As the code above shows, the view controller's view is the superview of the subviews.

Comment: Typically, you views are independent of each other, and you can't rely on the view controller to report back to each view what their siblings frames are going to be.  

My first thought is to implement layoutSubviews in your viewController and have the viewController be the arbiter of all the subviews' frames.

Otherwise, you need to implement methods that your views can call, possibly via a delegate, to get the viewController to do something similar to calling viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I think we're off base again. I'm trying for the view controller to be the arbiter of all it's subviews. The problem is that I don't know the subview's height when I'm setting it's frame because the subview has not run through the layoutSubviews method yet. That's where it would have laid out all it's subviews..but it hasn't yet.

Comment: What does the subview know about its own frame size that the view controller doesn't?  If the view is basing its own frame on values that it knows about, why not provide a method in your view class that the viewcontroller can call, to get the size it needs, and then in the viewController's layoutSubviews, you can set all the frames of all the views.

Comment: That was my initial solution. I called that method "calculateHeight" or "calculateHeightWithWidth:(int)width", depending on if the width would ever effect the height. I don't like this solution because I'm already effectively calculating the height in the layoutSubviews method by laying out and setting the frames of all the components. Seems like double work.

Comment: The subview knows it's own size because let's say it has a UILabel...and depending on if it's in landscape or portrait, that label may be tall and narrow, or wide and short...so when it lays out it's subviews, it can figure out how big it should be

Comment: I think this may be the only solution though...other than maybe programming in some constraints...

Comment: Here's one other idea.  Implement a layoutSubviews in the viewController.  Theoretically, after viewWillLayoutSubviews is called, then each view gets its layoutSubviews called, and then finally the viewController's layoutSubviews gets called.  So, what you want to do in viewWillLayoutSubviews, you can do in the view controller's layoutSubviews.  Use some logging to see if the order of the calls is as I expect.

Comment: accepting your answer because of your comments. first person who understood my problem! up way too late, must sleep now, but will try to implement your solution tomorrow morning.

Comment: Good luck.  Don't be afraid to refactor your code if you have to :-)

Comment: I think this strategy is about the same as the calculateHeight method that I used. It works well when the width of the subviews didn't affect the height. But can't seem to get it to work when it does. I forfeited this strategy and decided not to subclass UIView but rather just keep many arrays in the view controller (one for all the labels, one for all the images, etc). This saves me from having to do this dance. I'm sure I'll run into this problem again though...

Comment: I like how HTML and CSS handles layout much more than iOS! I like most things about iOS, but not how they handle layout...maybe I'm just new though...a side question, can all this be done with constraints...setting relational constraints so that the bottom of one subview is constrained to the top of the next one, etc?